# Magento 2.0.0, very slow, paths not good

Tags: magento2, installation, file-permissions

I installed magento 2.0.0 on my computer. OS: Windows 10
I downloaded ZIP archive with sample data from:   https://www.magentocommerce.com/download. Also, followed installation instructions from their documentation, I ran composer install, and after that, the installation was complete, successfully.

Firstly, it is very, very slow. Is this common behaviour for my OS, and similar?

Also, there are lots of files, images, etc for which the path is not good, and GET returns HTTP 404. Am I missing something important here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, after running:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```